# How to revert an entire git repository -- including all branches -- to a previous date?

Tags: git, repository, reset

I have screwed up my github repository.  I have pushed things to GitHub (not just local) that I wish I hadn't.  The repository has 20 "steps" with `Step1` merging into `Step2`, which merges into `Step3` and so on, all the way to `Step20`  It's quite badly messed up.

I want my ***entire*** repository to be reverted back to how things were on December 10, for ***all*** the branches in the whole repository.

I've seen a number of ways to do this for a given branch, and I guess I can do that twenty times, right?

However, I'm hoping there is a way to do it without checking out all twenty branches and setting each one back.

Comment: Looking on the bright side, your weekend plans have been made.

Comment: @Will Hehe -- that's fine.  Whatever it takes.  :-)

Comment: Well, it didn't take all weekend, but I was able to get things back in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have ever *removed* commits or *deleted* some branch name(s), or deleted and re-cloned your repository, this is actually quite easy for a typical setup.  This is in part due to:

> ... December 10 ...

which, at this time, is just ten days ago.  Things get harder after 30 or 90 days, due to reflog entry expiration.  (This assumes the default configuration in which you have not told Git to use a different retention time period.)

#### Background

The thing to remember here is that what Git stores is not *changes* and not *files*, but rather *commits*.  (Each commit stores files, so that Git indirectly stores files, but the level at which things are visible is the commit.)  Every commit is uniquely identified by some hash ID, which is a big ugly string like `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7`.  Normally, too, you only ever *add new commits* to a Git repository.  This is true even with operations that *seem* to remove commits, such as `git commit --amend` or `git rebase`.  The original commits—with their unchanging hash IDs that are exactly as permanent as the commits themselves—are still in your repository.

Each of your *branch names* simply acts as a pointer.  That is, each one stores *one* hash ID.  The one hash ID stored in `master` may be `5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7` today.  Tomorrow, after you make a new commit, it will be something else, but there will still only be *one* hash ID in `master`.

When you make a *new* commit, Git:

1. Packages up the full snapshot (from your index, aka staging area aka cache).  This makes a Git *tree object* (not something you normally need to care about) that gets its own hash ID.
2. Collects your log message, your name and email address and the current date/time, and so on.  To this, Git adds the tree hash from step 1, a `parent` line recording the *current* commit's hash ID from the branch name, and any other suitable metadata that Git wants to include.  From all of this data, Git makes a *commit object*, which acquires its own new, unique hash ID.

   (Part of the reason for the time stamp is to make sure that the hash ID is unique.  Otherwise, if you made a new snapshot that matched an old one, with the same parent and other metadata, you'd get the *old* commit's hash ID back!  That would make two branches collapse into one branch.  This isn't actually fatal—you can make this condition occur via trickery and scripting to make more than one commit per second, for instance, and it does actually work—but it's deeply surprising and has the potential to break some workflows.)
3. Records the hash ID from step 2 into the current branch name.  Voila, the branch now points to the *new* commit.  The new commit points back to the *previous* commit.

So, before making this new commit, if the name `master` points to some commit `H` (H here stands in for the actual hash ID) whose parent is `G`, with `G`'s parent being `F`, and so on, you have:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <--master
```

Afterward, if we have `I` stand in for the new commit, the picture is:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <--master
```

#### Reflogs

Whenever Git updates a reference, such as a branch name like `master`, Git records the *previous* value of that branch name into a log.  This log is called the *reflog* for the reference.  Each log entry has a date/time stamp on it as well, so that you can run `git reflog master` to have it spill out:

```
$ git reflog master
5d826e9729 master@{0}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
965798d1f2 master@{1}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
8a0ba68f6d master@{2}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
...
```

(This is my Git repository for Git, where not-very-interesting things happen on `master`: basically, I just fast-forward it all the time.)

These entries are numbered according to their recency in the log: `@{0}` is the current value, `@{1}` is the previous, `@{2}` is what had been previous when `@{1}` was `@{0}` and so on.  The default for `git reflog` is to print them out numbered, like this, but with `--date=relative`, it prints their *time stamps* instead:

```
5d826e9729 master@{11 days ago}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
965798d1f2 master@{12 days ago}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
```

and so on.

You can also use `--date=local`, and many other formats.  To see them all, read the `git log` documentation (`git reflog` is actually `git log -g`).  Try it with `--date=local` now though.

#### Your job

Imagine, then, that we have something simple like this:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <--master
```

(I've stopped drawing the internal arrows because it's too hard / annoying, as you'll see in a moment.  Just remember, they necessarily point *backwards:* you cannot make an old commit that refers forwards to a new commit that does not yet exist, because you don't know the hash ID of the new commit until *after* you make it.  Then it's too late, because *nothing* in *any* commit—or in fact, in any Git internal object—can *ever* be changed.)

In order to roll `master` back to the way it was yesterday, when it pointed to `H` instead of `I`, you just need to tell Git: *set the name `master` to point to commit `H` now.*  The result is:

```
             I
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Commit `I` isn't *gone*.  In fact, this just added a new entry to the reflog, so that `master@{1}` remembers the hash ID of `master` as of the time it pointed to `I`.  (That new reflog entry has the date-and-time stamp of "now".)

Eventually—after at least 30 days by default, and 90 days for most typical cases—Git will scan through the reflog for `master` and discard any entries that are too old.  But until at least 30 days from now, `master@{<something>}` will remember the hash ID of commit `I`.

All we have to do, then, is find out what *all the reflogs say* about *all the branches*.  *For each branch that existed ten days ago, which commit did that branch point-to?*

You could do this by enumerating all the branch names:

```
$ git branch
<list of names spills out, one of them probably marked `*` as current branch>
```

Then, for each name, you can run `git reflog --date=local name` and look for the entry that corresponds to December 10th.  This might be dated before the 10th, as in this case:

```
$ git reflog --date=local master
5d826e9729 master@{Sun Dec 9 11:03:46 2018}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
965798d1f2 master@{Sat Dec 8 07:53:19 2018}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
```

This means `5d826e9729` is the value `master` held on the 9th, with nothing newer since then, so it must also be the value `master` held on the 10th.

You can repeat this for every branch name and figure out which commit you want each of those names to identify.  If the branch didn't exist before the 10th, you may want to *delete* the branch entirely; be aware that if you do so, Git also deletes its reflog, so there is no going back from this.

There is, however, an easier way.  The reflog syntax allows you to write:

```
master@{10.days.ago}
```

or:

```
master@{10.dec.2018}
```

to have Git itself figure this out!  In general, any Git command that takes a hash ID takes this as well.  For instance, `git rev-parse` turns a name into the corresponding hash ID:

```
$ git rev-parse master
5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
```

but:

```
$ git rev-parse master@{8.dec.2018}
965798d1f2992a4bdadb81eba195a7d465b6454a
```

I used `8 dec` here since my reflog doesn't have anything interesting later than that.  Note that what came out is `96579...`, which is `master@{1}`, which *is* from the 8th.

Watch out though: if you have *more than one* value on your selected day, Git will pick *one* of them.  In fact, `8.dec.2018` means *midnight* on that day, and you can add more time specifiers if you want 0900 or 1432 or whatever.  Beware of time zone issues as well—make sure you pick the right reflog entry!

#### Automating this

Instead of manually invoking `git branch`, copying the names, and then manually doing each one, you can start with this:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads |
    while read branch; do echo git branch -f $branch $branch@{10.dec}; done
```

which prints out the commands that it *would* run, if it had `echo` taken out.

If they look OK, and you're really sure that this is all correct, you can now take out the `echo` to make the commands actually happen.

(This assumes an sh/bash compatible command line interpreter.)

Comment: Thank you -- you have provided a thorough and educational answer that sadly doesn't appear to work for me.  I get "log only goes back to <three days ago>" error when I do what you suggested.  Now, I *know* that the repository goes back farther than that on GitHub -- I can see it clearly there.  So how do I make my *local* repository go back to a date on my *remote* origin?  Thanks again so much.

Comment: I should add that the command I tried was git branch -f Step2 'Step2@{10.days.ago}'

Comment: That's where *or deleted and re-cloned your repository* comes in. The reflog entries are *local to one specific repository*. You must find the repository (or all the various clones) in which you made changes, so that you can locate the reflog entry from the 10-days-ago event. If they were all in one clone, it's easy. If you changed branch A in clone A, and branch B in clone B, it's obviously harder.